# I am confused as to which nonparametric procedure I should be performing on my data

Tags: self-study, anova, nonparametric

My question reads:
"A computer laboratory manager was interested in whether there
was a difference in functioning time for three different branded
battery packs for laptop. The manager took a random sample of six
battery packs of each brand and tested them. The results, in hours
of functioning before the need for a recharge, were recorded as
follows:

```
 Brand 1       Brand 2      Brand 3
  6.75          7.80          6.25 
  7.30          7.65          6.54 
  7.60          7.72          6.20
  7.50          7.85          6.35
  6.90          7.45          6.39
  7.25          7.00          6.95
```

As the manager was unsure whether the assumptions for the usual
parametric analysis of variance were valid, she decided to employ
nonparametric methods. Use the appropriate nonparametric
procedure to determine whether the distribution of functioning time
before needing to be recharged is the same for the three brands of
battery packs. Use $α$ = 0.05."

I am unsure how to determine which nonparametric procedure to use for this question. Every procedure seems to talk about only using 2 populations instead of 3. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: One approach is to identify the name of a *parametric* procedure and then search for it along with the word "nonparametric," as in https://www.google.com/search?q=nonparametric+anova .  It's a good way to leverage what you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Kruskall Wallis one-way analysis of variance.

Kruskall-Wallis test extends the two sample non-parametric Mann-Whitney U-test for comparing multiple groups. Opposed to parametric One-Way-ANOVA test it makes no assumptions about the normality of the distribution. Still, when testing differences in medians it assumes the distributions to have the shame shape, meaning it basically has the same non-heteroscedasticy assumption as does One-Way-ANOVA. If testing for any differences between groups that affect the mean ranks, no assumptions are made.

Comment: I agree with this. It would be better if you can explain *why* though....